# Can I store some methods in a class and use them in another activity?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I have an Android app which uses a lot of activities. All those activities contain methods that are the same in every activity. Can I put those methods into another class (one which just contains those methods) and access them whenever needed in my activities??

I thought about putting the methods in a class and then import that class in my activities. Would that work? Would I be able to use those methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a helper class. This can take methods you can call from every point of your program. Often this classes takes static methods like:

```
public class Helper {
   public static int callMeFromTheActivities() {
     //do some work
   }
}
```

so you can call it from your activities like:

```
Helper.callMeFromTheActivities();
```